# How can I use grep to see if my word in a array has a match with list of word in dictionary and extract the exact single word?

Tags: perl, grep

Thanks for the answers... i am trying the different possibilities with all your answers.
one thing: i could not be that much clearer in asking question to you all, ie. i m applying this RE in my local script/character(similar to Tibetan Script) and not in English word.

```
foreach my $word (@list)
{
  if(grep(/$word/, $dict))       # i have dict in scalar ($dict)
       {
           print "Matched and Found\n";
        }
    else
      {
         print "Not Matched\n";
      }
}
```

Focus is to extract on single matched, exact word. i tried using /\b$word\b/... that doesnot seem to work in our script... where our word is made up of multisyllable and each syllable is separated by (.)(Tibetan Tsheg).

**Additional information:**

> ***For the beginner the most challenging feature of the Tibetan sentence is the lack of separation between words.*** ... Since there is no space after a word, the reader must figure out each word based on context and location in the sentence. Looking up these two letters in a dictionary might lead you to think that this sentence is starting with a reference to the surface of earth. However, the rest of the sentence, its context, and the lack of an agentive case connector, indicates that these two letters are not words by themselves, but rather the word "yesterday". From this you can see it's good to first evaluate a sentence as a whole, by identifying it's various elements, rather than translate it word by word.

Emphasis added. See http://www.learntibetan.net/grammar/sentence.htm

Comment: i am trying to extract complete and exact word... i even tried /^word$/.... one thing: the word/characters are not english alphabets... i m using my local language... Dzongkha script..(similar to Tibetan script)...Thanks for the comments...

Comment: How are the words separated in `$dict`?

Comment: i loaded the dictionary at once (slurp). and assigned to $dict... can it be done in another way to suit my need.  Any further advice/answers are welcome... since i being perl newbie...

Comment: @Cthar well, then, what is the format of the dictionary file?

Comment: @Sinan It is text file... ie dict.txt.

Comment: @Sinan  and it contains about 20,000 head word entries.

Comment: @Cthar You are making it needlessly difficult to help you. I am voting to close this duplicate question. You should edit/update your original question with the format of the dictionary file by specifying how words are separated from their definitions and what signifies the end of a definition. You may also want to read http://prog21.dadgum.com/29.html

Comment: Syntax was better before you changed `@dict` to `$dict`. The `grep` function operates on a list.

Comment: @Cthar - please don't post duplicates (now merged); edit the original question to make any clarifications etc.

Comment: Learning more about the problem at hand: http://www.learntibetan.net/grammar/sentence.htm

Comment: So, given some test, you need to first identify the *words* in that text. This is difficult enough in English. On the other hand, if, as I suspect, words are not separated at all (but syllables are) and the larger context of the sentence is required to decide if you have, say, two separate syllables versus a two-syllable word in the sentence, how can this problem be solved using a regular expression? My guess is it cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the dictionary in a string and using grep to search it is going to be very slow for a dictionary of any size.  Have you considered using a hash for the dictionary?  I.e.

```
$dict = { word1 => 1, word2 => 1....... etc } # for example...

for my $word (@list) 
{ 
   if ($dict->{$word})
   {
      print "Matched\n";
   }
   else
   {
      print "Not matched\n";
   }
}
```

Note that I don't advocate creating the hash in this manner, this is just an example to show using a hash as a dictionary, with the keys being the words and the values a constant 'true' value.  If the matching has to be case-insensitive you would lowercase the dictionary words before inserting them into the hash, and lowercase $word before doing the lookup.

EDIT: Here's some code to load the dictionary from a file with one word per line

```
open(FH,'dictionary.txt');
$dict = { map {chomp; $_,1} <FH> }
close(FH)
```

Explanation:

1. <FH> in list context reads the
   entire file
2. The map function evaluates the block
       ( the stuff in braces) for each line
3. The block removes the newline and
       returns a two-element list
       containing the word and '1'
4. The entire returned list is used to
   initialize a hash
5. A reference to the hash is stored in
   $dict

Comment: Any reason you're using `$dict` is a hash reference instead of `%dict` as a hash?  I'm not sure it matters (other than saving you the trouble of typing `->`).  Just curious.

Comment: Just force of habit.  My background is Java, where everything is a reference, so I'm more comfortable looking at things that way :-)

Comment: i have loaded the dict(wordlist) from external file and slurp into $dict... how is external loaded file assigned to hash... Sorry, question may seem nonsense... since i being a perl newbie...
thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Cthar How can we figure out how to load a file into a hash if we have no idea how the file is formatted?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fond of

```
grep { $_ =~ /blah/} @foo
```

That lets me modify the condition later easier than a straight

```
grep(/blah/, @foo)
```

But I don't see anything wrong with your syntax.

Comment: Why do you think that let's you edit the condition easier? I prefer the block form, but it's only easier when you want to have multiple statements.

Comment: I can do do something like changing it to an `eq` operator, or calling a complex match-type function instead. It's simpler if I just go with the general block operator.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own code to compare every element of @list against every element of @dict, use a module that already does the job for you, like [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Compare):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

my @dict = qw(apple banana orange grape pomegranate);
my @list = qw(banana giraffe pomegranate apple);

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@dict, \@list);
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;

print "words found in the dictionary: " . join(', ', @intersection) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your grep syntax is fine.

I feel compelled to comment on your algorithm, though. It is very wasteful.

You iterate over `@dict` once for every word in `@list`.

It would be faster to assign one array into the keys of a hash and do lookups on the hash:

```
my %lut;
@lut{@list} = ();

for my $word ( @dict ) {
    print exists $lut{$word} ? "Matched and Found\n" : "Not Matched\n";
}
```

Hash lookups happen in constant time and so instead of a nested loop, you have a flat loop.  As your word lists grow, speed differences should become quite apparent.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`List::Util::first`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util#first) for that. It stops processing the list after the first answer. `grep` won't do that.

```
if( defined first { /$word/ } @list ) {
    print "Matched and Found\n";
}
else {
    print "Not Matched\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy: nothing is wrong.
I can run that code just fine in Perl, and it works as intended.
The problem must be somewhere else.  Are you using "use strict;" at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax. It's just not very Perlish. In fact, your code says "Hi there, I have a C background!". Thus, for a start, I'd get rid of the parens after `grep`.

But what really needs some more thought is your regular expression. What if `@list` contained 'sex', but `@dict` contained 'Essex'? I'd change that regular expression to:

```
m/^$word$/i
```

Comment: That would be the next logical step.

Comment: yeah... thats the problem with me... i just want 'sex' and it show all the words that contain 'sex'. i have a list of word and each of those word are searched in $wordlist.... thanks for answers...

Answer (score 0):

In Perl 5.10, we have smart matching!

```
foreach my $word (@list) {
  say $word ~~ @dict ? 'Matched and Found' : 'Not Matched';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Tibetan script. The example below assumes your dictionary consists of words followed by an equal sign and the definition of the word on each line.

It uses [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Slurp) to efficiently slurp the file as list of lines, [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)s each line and splits it to get the word as the key and the definition as the value in the `%dict` hash.

It assumes that the `@words` already contains individual words and words do not need to be identified from an arbitrary text such as `"a.a.b.a.b.b.a.a.b.a"` (see my remark pointing out that words are not separated in Tibetan, only syllables are).

To modify the code to read the dictionary from an external file, replace `\*DATA` with the name of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my @words = qw( a b a.b b.a a.a b.a.b);

my %dict = map { chomp; split /\s*=\s*/ } read_file \*DATA;

for my $word ( @words ) {
    if ( defined(my $defn = $dict{$word}) ) {
        print "'$word' means $defn\n";
    }
    else {
        print "'$word' not found\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
a = Letter 1
b = Letter 2
a.b = Letter 1 and Letter 2
b.a = Letter 2 and Letter 1
a.b.a = Letter 1 and Letter 2 and Letter 1
b.a.b = Letter 2 and Letter 1 and Letter 2
```

Output:

```
'a' means Letter 1
'b' means Letter 2
'a.b' means Letter 1 and Letter 2
'b.a' means Letter 2 and Letter 1
'a.a' not found
'b.a.b' means Letter 2 and Letter 1 and Letter 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use word boundary to match the word as it is from the dictionary. (A word is surrounded by one or more spaces except beginning and ending of a page).

You can go with this

```
$dict ="squirrel in my pocket ";

@list =(squirrel,in,me,poc);

foreach my $word (@list)
{
  if(grep(/\b$word\b/, $dict))       
  {
    print "\$word:$word  Matched with     \$dict :$dict \n";
  }
  else
  {
   print "\$word:$word  Not Matched with \$dict :$dict \n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$word:squirrel  Matched     with  $dict :squirrel in my pocket
$word:in        Matched     with  $dict :squirrel in my pocket
$word:me        Not Matched with  $dict :squirrel in my pocket
$word:poc       Not Matched with  $dict :squirrel in my pocket
```